# How to delete an item from a list in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I just started to learn React Native.
I am trying to create a simple app that has a button which will delete the last element of a list and the list will be updated after that. The problem here is that the whole list is deleted when I click the button. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

```
    //delete Item from the list
    class ButtonDelete extends Component{
     constructor(props){
       super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      }
      handleChange(){
     this.props.deleteItem();
  }
  render(){
    const data = this.props.data;
    return(
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Greetings name = {item.key} ></Greetings>}
        />
        <Button
        onPress={this.handleChange}
        title="Delete"
        color="#841584"
        />
      </View>

    );
  }
}


export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]
    }
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
  }

    deleteItem() {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          data: prevState.data.pop()
      }));
      }


  render() {
    const data = this.state.data;
    return (
      <View>
        <ButtonDelete data = {data}
        deleteItem={this.deleteItem}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array.pop()` does not return a new array without the removed element. It alters the original array.

In my opinion the best solution would be to use `slice` in order to get back a new array without the last element which you can use to update your state, so your delete function will look kind of something like this:

```
deleteItem() {
   const newArray = this.state.data.slice(0, -1)

   this.setState({
       data: newArray
   });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace your **deleteItem()** method with this. Because `pop()` removes the top element of your array and returns that element. It does not return the list with the object removed.

```
deleteItem() {
    let items = this.state.data;
    items.pop();

    this.setState({ data: items });
}
```

Comment: Since you've already mutated the state you might as well just do `items.pop(); this.setState({ });`